# Query Google Sheets Using SQL Via Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a way to issue SQL queries to a Google Sheet using Python.

I know that Google Sheets has a function called `query` that can be used to issue SQL queries from within the spreadsheet itself,

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

Is there some way that I can call this function using Python? Maybe through the `gspread` module?

I expected there to be a way to call Google Sheets functions (like COUNT, SUM and others) using this package.

I am open to trying other methods as well. Basically, I want to query a Google Sheet like a database using Python.

Comment: I Read through gsheets and google-api-python-file (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) and found nothing of the sorts

Comment: You could possibly capture the request and see if you could replicate it in python

Comment: seems like you might want to be using Google Cloud's BigQuery rather than google sheets.  just sharing link in case you didn't know it existed:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Comment: QUERY is a function from sheets, from the api you can get a cell or range and insert that function there. From the question, you want to get the values from the sheet to your app, is that right? If so, why not using the API methods?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a direct way to accomplish this using only the Google Sheets API, but I would use `pandas` and `pandasql` to accomplish this.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as psql
.
.
.
# After authenticating with Google Sheets and opening the data-filled sheet  

# Get all values from the sheet and store them in a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())

# Prepare the query
query = "SELECT * FROM df WHERE ColumnName = 'Value'"

# Execute the query
result = psql.sqldf(query, locals())

# Display the result
print(result)
```

If you find this answer useful, please vote it up.